# jQuery post array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am wondering how to post an array using $.ajax. My array is something like this:

```
var a = new Array();
a['test'] = 1;
a['test2'] = 2;
and so on...
```

I tried:

```
$.ajax({
  url: baseUrl+"chat.php",
  data: { vars: a},
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data) {
alert(data);
}});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong, how are you trying to access the data in the php?

Comment: And have you used some kind of traffic watch to make sure the call is getting to the chat.php page?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var a = {};
a['test'] = 1;
a['test2'] = 2;

// or


var a = {};
a.test = 1;
a.test2 = 2;

// or


var a = {
    test : 1,
    test2 : 2
};

$.ajax({
  url: baseUrl+"chat.php",
  data: a,
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

You may then access the data in your PHP script like this:

```
$_POST['test'];
$_POST['test2'];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the style of an `<input>` element where the name field is `test[]` and the array indices are auto incremented?

Comment: @Kevin_TA, just use `{ test: ["array", "of", "values"] }` as the `data` argument for `$.ajax`. It will get serialized to `test[]=array&test[]=of&test[]=values`.

Comment: "a" is an object, not an array in this example. Any ordering will be lost.

Comment: @sivann that's what the OP wanted. His `a` array is actually just an object.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan it's not an object, it says new Array(). Now if that solution was ok with him that's another matter :-)

Comment: @sivann it says `new Array`, but it's used like an ordinary object, i.e. `{}`. At that point you lose all ordering guarantees. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8067675/58808

Answer (score 16):

I used this:

```
var newArray = new Array();
newArray.push("item1");
newArray.push("item2");
newArray.push("item3");

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: urlToPost,
    data: JSON.stringify(newArray),
    contentType: "application/json"
   });
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer doing it this way:

ie.

```
var data = [{ name: 'test1', value: 'test data' }, { name: 'test2', value: 'test data' }];

$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'url',
    data: data,
   });
```

Server side (PHP): `$_POST['test1'];` `$_POST['test2'];`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how I pass arrays (from real-life code) :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: { CartID : cartID, 'Manufacturers[]' : manufacturers, 'PartNumbers[]' : partNumbers },
  success: function(res)
  {
    ...
  },
  dataType: "json",
  async: false
});
```

then on the server-side:

```
$cartID = $_POST['CartID'];
$manufacturers = $_POST['Manufacturers'];
$partNumbers = $_POST['PartNumbers'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest version

```
$.post(url, { 'test[]': myArray });
```

Server side: `$myArray = $_POST['test'];`