# jQuery post no duplicate parameter name

Tags: jquery, post

I'm making a simple post:

```
jQ.post(url, {id:1, id:2, id:3});
```

However, jQuery only posts one of the "id" parameters, value 3 being the latest it sends id=3.
How to make it send all of them, so the output is without array brackets?

```
id=1&id=2&id=3
```

Comment: not possible. you're defining the same object key 3 times, so only the LAST one in the chain gets left. you probably want `{id:[1,2,3]}` instead.

Comment: i think the issue here is that the parameter object has the same property being set 3 times, you should try making an array as detailed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950673/jquery-post-array

Comment: Use JSON.Stringify on Marc B's input and provide other details to post call. Refer to this if you are trying ajax call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring

Answer (score 2):

Send an array

```
jQ.post(url, {ids:[1, 2, 3]});
```

Comment: it adds [] to the "id": id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3, but sends, though I need them without []

Comment: @Yan, `id[]=1&id[]=2....` is standard query string syntax used to signify an array. In your backend, you can change your code logic to deal with an array of ids

Comment: I understand but unfortunately, it is configured to receive the sequence posted above.

Comment: @Yan, out of curiosity, what is the  backend language/framework you are using? `php`, `.net`, `java`,....?

Comment: I'm not sure which backend it uses, but most likely PHP. I can also confirm that the website does send then without [] by looking at post parameters. So there should be a way to do that.

Comment: Correction it is running .NET

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

```
var obj = {id: [1,2,3]};
var serializedObj = $.param(obj, true);

$.post(url,serializedObj,function(){});
```

Original answer by Kevin Bowersox
[JQuery parameter serialization without the bracket mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540827/jquery-parameter-serialization-without-the-bracket-mess)